Где хранить refreshToken на фронте?
Пытаюсь разобраться с JWT авторизацией применительно к фронтенд приложению.
Есть 2 токена

Первый авторизационный accessToken у которого время жизни
маленькое (15 минут для примера)
Второй refreshToken который нужен для обновления/перевыпуска accessToken-а. У refreshToken время жизни большое (30 дней например)

Из документации - "Предполагается что refreshToken нужно хранить в неком очень защищенном месте на фронте".
Объясните пожалуйста что это за место. Если кто-то внедрил вредоносный js код в приложение, как обезопасить refreshToken?
Я знаю только о куке с флагом httpOnly, которая недоступна из javaScript.
Что если нет возможности выставить куку? Какие ещё варианты безопасного хранения токена есть?

Во 1 можно хранить куки без сервера вот код.
Во 2 я советую хранить accessToken в sessionStorage, а refreshToken в LocalStorage с проверкой времени по интервалу(но это может быть небезопасно)

Самое простое решение - используйте для сервера Laravel - и соответственно их пакеты Sanctum или Passport. В них пакетно все реализовано (и с вопросами безопасности) и конечно настраиваемые.
